# putting html inside an iframe (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Can I create an empty iframe as a placeholder to later insert html into it?

In otherwords, suppose I have an empty iframe with an id,

How do I insert html in it?

I'm using jquery, if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do it without jQuery also:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeID');
iframe = iframe.contentWindow || ( iframe.contentDocument.document || iframe.contentDocument);

iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write('Hello World!');
iframe.document.close();
```

jQuery's html strips body, html and head tags from the inserted HTML.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `<html foo="bar"></html>`. Note that the iframe must be inserted into its parent document.

Comment: Working like a charm when loading "document.write" scripts from AJAX requests

Comment: `iframe = iframe.contentWindow || ( iframe.contentDocument.document || iframe.contentDocument);`

Comment: This is not the correct method. This has no function.

Answer (score 37):

View the source of this page: http://mg.to/test/dynaframe.html It appears to do exactly what you want to do.

```
$(function() {
    var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
    $('body').html( $frame );
    setTimeout( function() {
        var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
        var $body = $('body',doc);
        $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
    }, 1 );
});
```

Comment: This only copies the `body` element, when you might need the `head` element, or even the attributes of the `html` element.

Answer (score 9):

No it's not. You would modify the script like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $frame = $('iframe');
    setTimeout( function() {
            var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
            var $body = $('body',doc);
            $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
    }, 1 );
});
```

Comment: Why setTimeout?

Answer (score 5):

```
iframeElementContainer =   document.getElementById('BOX_IFRAME').contentDocument;
iframeElementContainer.open();
iframeElementContainer.writeln("<html><body>hello</body></html>");
iframeElementContainer.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I know that is possible but the main problem is that we cannot handle a frame from outside it i has already loaded some other thing.

```
$(function() {
        var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
        $('body').html( $frame );
        setTimeout( function() {
                var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
                var $body = $('body',doc);
                $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
        }, 1 );
});
```

but if we start as

```
<iframe src="http:/www.hamrobrt.com">
<---Your Script to put as you like--->
```

Then its impossible to hit that out.

Answer (score 0):

> I have same problem, Where I have to show html code snippet in iframe dynamically from database without SRC attribute of iframe and I fixed same problem with following code
>
> I hope this would help someone who has same requirement I had.

[jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/hywpfceh/)

HTML :

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="iframe"></iframe>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="iframe"></iframe>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="iframe"></iframe>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="iframe"></iframe>
```

JS

```
<script>
var doc,$body;
var txt = Array(
            '<style>body{background-color:grey} h1{background-color:red;font-weight:900}</style><h1>Cool!!! this is text for</h1><p>First Iframe</p>',
            '<style>body{background-color:pink}h1{background-color:green;font-weight:200}</style><h1>Cool This is Text for</h1><p> second Iframe',
            '<style>body{background-color:yellow}h1{font-weight:400}</style><h1>Cool..... This is text FOR : </h1> <div>3rd Iframe</div>',
            '<style>body{background-color:blue} h1{font-weight:400}</style><h1>Cool This is text for Fourth iframe</h1>'
            );
$('.iframe').each(function(index,value){
    doc = $('iframe')[index].contentWindow.document;
        $body = $('body',doc);
        $body.html(txt[index]);
});
</script>
```