# Insert HTML into iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, insert

I am creating a in browser HTML editor.  I am using the syntax highlighter called Code Mirror which is very good.

My setup is an iframe that holds a view of the page which is being edited and a textarea which the plain text HTML sits which the user edits.

I am trying to insert the edited HTML from the textarea into the iframe which displays they rendered HTML.

Is this possible? I have tried the following:

HTML setup:

```
<iframe id="render">

</iframe>

<textarea id="code">
HTML WILL BE 

HERE
</textarea>
<input type="submit" id="edit_button" value="Edit" />
```

JQuery Setup:

```
$('#edit_button').click(function(){
    var code = editor.getCode(); // editor.getCode() is a codemirror function which gets the HTML from the text area
    var iframe = $('#render');
    iframe.html(code)
})
```

This does not seem to load the HTML into the iframe, is there a special method to insert HTML into a iframe or is this not possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [putting html inside an iframe (using javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620881/putting-html-inside-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Set the [document.designMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.designMode) property and then try adding the HTML.

See also: [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)

Comment: The links are broken

Answer (score 29):

This problem bugged me too and finally found solution.

Its late but will add value to other visitors who might need proper fix.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Iframe test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
            $('body').html( $frame );
            setTimeout( function() {
                var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
                var $body = $('body',doc);
                $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
            }, 1 );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would you create the iframe in javascript? that seems like such a terrible way to do it...

Answer (score 14):

You can do it all on one line with jquery

```
$("iframe").contents().find('html').html("Your new HTML");
```

See working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/dWpvf/972/

Replace "iframe" with "#render" for your example.  I left in "iframe" so that other users can reference the answer.

Comment: Not sure why the accepted answer has been downvoted, but for future viewers to this question, this method is brilliant and works :)

Comment: a concise answer. Thank alot

Answer (score 3):

try

```
iframe[0].documentElement.innerHTML = code;
```

Assuming that the url to the iframe is from the same domain as the webpage.