# jQuery UI modal box affecting page styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI's modal box for previewing some html content which added to a text area.I f I add some style for the html in textarea, after I close the box, it is affecting my page stylings. I mean these styles are applied if there is any matching element. How can I prevent this ?

I am using the following code for displaying the modal box

```
$("#preview_button").click(function() {
     $('#preview').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false,width:960,height:400,dialogClass:'dialog_style1',title: "Email Content Preview"});
     $( "#preview" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] );
     $('#preview').html($('#email_content').val());
     $('#preview').dialog('open');
});
```

Here is the JS filddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7as4f/6/

Comment: Code(http://jsfiddle.net/) or it never happend :D

Comment: @ValiD now added here http://jsfiddle.net/7as4f/6/ Please add some HTML with <style> specified

Comment: Removed first 2 included scripts as you were adding jquery and jqueryui twice, my jsfiddle seems ok http://jsfiddle.net/validide/7as4f/7/

Comment: Happening there also. Please add http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-16/example.html this pages source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the html in the textbox when displaying the modal. You can prevent that by loading the html into an `iframe` and then display the iframe. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565822/insert-html-into-iframe)