# How to show the scroll bars of a content-editable div only when it has reached its max height?

Tags: html, css

I find that the scroll bars (disabled or enable) will show up on the sides of the div despite whether or not the element has reached its max length. Just by putting overflow: value; it will automatically display them. How do I make it so that the scroll bars will only show when the element has reached it's max height?

Comment: I can only guess, but are you trying to build a wysiwyg editor? If so I would recommend you changing from div to an iframe as the stage object. Easier to handle, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059976/maintaining-aesthetic-scroll-in-contenteditable-div/5063142#5063142)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using overflow: auto should only produce scrollbars when the height is exceeded.

```
div.scrollbars {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use

```
overflow: auto
```

In your style.  This should only add the scroll bars if they are necessary.  See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp