# Using iframe instead of createpopup doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I used an `iframe` instead of `window.createPopup`, but it gives me an error in the console like "oDucument is not defiend".

Here's my code:

```
function ShowDropdown(oMenu, oMenuDropDown){
//Set popup html
var iframe='<iframe class="adframe" id="111" name="widget" src="#" width="300" height="250" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
var oframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var oDocument = oframe.document;
oDocument.open();
var sHTML = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../style.css'></head><body topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bottommargin=0 style='overflow:visible;border-width:0px;'>"
            + oMenuDropDown.innerHTML + "</body></html>";
oDocument.write(sHTML);
oDocument.close();

//show popup
iframe.show(0, 0, 207, 50);}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some really random things here.

```
var iframe='<iframe class="adframe" id="111" name="widget" src="#" width="300" height="250" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
```

You now have a string called "iframe", containing some HTML.
But you never use that string, except when calling

```
iframe.show(0, 0, 207, 50);
```

which most likely gives you an error because strings have no `.show()` function.

Parallel to that you create an iframe:

```
var oframe = document.createElement('iframe');
```

Assign it some contents:

```
var oDocument = oframe.document;
oDocument.open();
var sHTML = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../style.css'></head><body topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bottommargin=0 style='overflow:visible;border-width:0px;'>"
        + oMenuDropDown.innerHTML + "</body></html>";
oDocument.write(sHTML);
oDocument.close();
```

But then that's it, you don't do anything with it.

And if the error you get really says `oDucument`, then it must be outside of the code you show here, because there is no `oDucument` at all.
Also, `oDocument` is `undefined` because `oframe.document` doesn't exist, it's `oframe.contentWindow.document`, but even that will only be available after the iframe has been added to the DOM tree and has finished loading.

A much simpler solution would be to use a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419102/2302862)):

```
function ShowDropdown(oMenu, oMenuDropDown)
{
    // Construct the element purely in JS:
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.className = 'adframe';
    iframe.id = '111';
    iframe.name = 'widget';
    iframe.width = 300;
    iframe.height = 250;
    iframe.marginWidth = 0;
    iframe.marginHeight = 0;
    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
    iframe.scrolling = 'no';
    // Set the position:
    iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    iframe.style.top = '50px'; // Change this value to what you need
    iframe.style.left = '300px'; // Change this value to what you need
    // Set the contents:
    var sHTML = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css"></head><body topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bottommargin="0" style="overflow:visible;border-width:0px">' + oMenuDropDown.innerHTML + '</body></html>';
    iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURI(sHTML);
    // Show popup:
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Also, consider removing the `oMenu` parameter since you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

`iframe` elements don't have a `show` method, so going this way won't achieve what you're probably trying to do.
You should probably put your dialog content in a positioned `div` and show that.

As for the error message, an `iframe` has no document property, and so it returns null. Calling `open` on a null value generates your error.

Comment: *iframe elements don't have a show method* — That doesn't matter (yet), `show()` is being called on a string, not an iframe element (although strings don't have that method either) and the error is about trying to call `open` on `oframe.document`, not about calling `show`.

Comment: What I was stating is that the entire solution won't work, regardless of the error, and the fact that the code ALSO confuses the ```iframe``` and ```oframe``` variables is irrelevant. As I wrote, the error is that there is no ```document``` property there.