# Using Stripe with Google Apps Script without redirect

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up Stripe payments in such a way that it doesn't take the user out of the GAS custom modal. The modal is triggered when the user clicks a button to become a premium member in a custom sidebar the Add-On provides.

As far as I know Apps Script do not allow for redirects, so the stripe example below doesn't work as it depends on the user getting redirected to stripe's payment portal.

This is the example: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client-subscription#enable-checkout

At one point it should redirect the user to a Stripe page for the payment gateway.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Free</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae vitae illum, commodi facilis labore
                dicta? Culpa corporis qui veritatis exercitationem fuga cumque, ad ex ea quod dolorem esse
                consequuntur a?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Premium</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptatem nostrum nulla doloremque
                impedit obcaecati nesciunt illum quidem sapiente nihil, tempore suscipit error nam numquam, culpa
                facilis minus, eum repudiandae!</p>
            <button id="checkout-button-plan_" target="_top" class="btn-small">1 year
                - 12€</button>
            <label for="checkout-button-plan_">30 days free, cancel any time</label>
            <div id="error-message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');

            var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-plan_');
            checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
                // them to Checkout.
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                        items: [{
                            plan: 'plan_GGOGMuQ5nh',
                            quantity: 1
                        }],

                        // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
                        // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
                        // a successful payment.
                        // Instead use one of the strategies described in
                        // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
                        successUrl: 'https://demo.org/success',
                        cancelUrl: 'https://demo.org/canceled',
                    })
                    .then(function (result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                            // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
                            var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                        }
                    });
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

Right now the action is blocked since the modal doesn't have the permission to redirect the user.

1. What (if this is even possible anymore with Stripe) is the proper way of doing this in GAS, completing the payment all from within the modal?
2. What would be your suggested approach if the above is blocked or simply not practical?

I'm right now leaning towards dealing with payments in a separate web page altogether. I am not in favor of sending the user away from the Spreadsheet though, and would like to avoid it if possible, while still retaining the possibility of allowing for SCA-regulated payments.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

*Update: Error message*

```
v3:1 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://docs.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-xdlpqop7hu3az75jfccpm6uaaujayexlmqjnkoq-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

    (anonymous) @ v3:1
    v3:1 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://docs.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://[...]script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

(anonymous) @ v3:1
v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/ppage_[...]'.
    at https://js.stripe.com/v3:1:120966
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sc (https://js.stripe.com/v3:1:120728)
    at ws (https://js.stripe.com/v3:1:137767)
    at https://js.stripe.com/v3:1:139074
```

*Update: Markup + JS used to open modal*

**Markup in sidebar:**

```
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="center">
                <b>Free version</b>| <a href="">Support</a>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <button class="btn-small grey lighten-3 teal-text" onclick="showSubscriptionModal(event)">Upgrade
                    membership </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>
<script>
    function showSubscriptionModal(event) {
        alert("called!");
        google.script.run.showSubscriptionModal();
    }
</script>
```

**JS in codefile:**

```
const showSubscriptionModal = () => {
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('subscription');
  const html = template.evaluate().setTitle('Subscription and Payments');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Subscription and Payments');
};

export default showSubscriptionModal;
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about using Web Apps? And if you use Google Docs, how about using the dialog and sidebar? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. When you provide more information about the relationship between your goal and the use of Google Apps Script, it might be help users think of the solution and workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike for your comment and politeness, much appreciated. Apologies for the lack of elaboration - I have updated the question to try to make it a bit more clear. Please let me know if this makes more sense now. Thank you for your contributions so far on SO - you've already helped me a lot!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you are trying to use Stripe API on the add-on of Google Docs. I could understand like this. In this case, Javascript can be used. But from your question, you say `Right now the action is blocked since the modal doesn't have the permission to redirect the user.`. From this situation, for example, can this method in the API be used for your situation? https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges For example, you can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58635015). But I'm not sure whether this is useful. So if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but are you trying to put that HTML you got from Stripe into a sidebar (as an example) on your spreadsheet? If so, how are you doing it? What problems are you facing?

Comment: @ZektorH - I'm trying to put it in a custom modal. The problem I'm facing is that nothing happens on click, except I get errors in the console stating that the action (redirecting) isn't permitted.

Comment: Please include the full error message on your question as well as the code you are using to display the modal.

Comment: @ZektorH - Added error message + modal-relevant code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269967/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-initiate-navigation-for-frame-with-url)