# How to dynamically insert html which may contain link and script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I am using jQuery to build a web pages which displays emails. The emails are read from a REST service and can be in plain text and or html.

So far, all the mails I've tested which are in html format have just body content - i.e. no `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>`. Today I got a mail in html format which had a whole document. The head and body tags get filtered out (by the browser presumably) but my problem is that the styles used by the mail are fetched from the sender's web site.

These raises a whole set of questions about security etc. Should my app allow such links at all? Should I extract the `link` and `script` tags and insert them in my page `head`?

Is there another solution similar to `iframe`?

Comment: Just seen that there is a way to dynamically fill an iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an iframe to show the contents of your mail. This way you can rely on browser security features and mitigate XSS vulnerabilities.

The service sending your HTML content should strip script tags and also set the [content-security-policy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet#HTTP_Headers) header to disable inline-scripts.

Even if you want to allow script execution within an email (which I don't assume), an iframe provides better isolation than injecting the mail content into your own DOM.

Comment: An iFrame provides very few isolation, actually. XSS can happens without `script`. In addition `script' is executed on the client-side. What can it do, maybe displaying porn, or unfair things, or steal local infos ? local Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should really **reject** the scripts.

Anyway, of course you can dynamically load/fill an iframe. Simply update its `src`. iFrame is not a security insurance thought.

> Note : your question is not a code issue. Should not be posted here IMO.

Comment: I don't have a src (html file) but see that there is a way to fill the iframe directly

Comment: But it is a general software engineering question adressing important web security issues

Comment: @paul Good, script should not be that dangerous, but there is no reason scripting a mail, such thing is suspect. Filter scripts out.

Answer (score 0):

An iFrame provides very few isolation - at least it isolates css styles... -, actually. XSS can happens without `script`. In addition `script` is executed on the client-side. What can it do, maybe displaying porn, or unfair things, or steal local infos ? local Storage ?   displaying `html` is really so few dangerous for your system. XSS works in forms, forms are targetted cause - behind - there is database processes. But if you only display `html`, omg, you can keep it cool. Just remove script cause **there is no reason for having script in a mail**

And no need to feel affraid cause anyone talks about *SQL injection*, *XSS* and so third. Stating there is no form, no ajax, in your case, this is ridiculous, sorry, to answer there is risks.
**You have nothing to fear in displaying HTML.** Save your time.

Comment: Not true. No database or form needed for XSS. If an attacker knows about a user using paul's software he can send the user a malicious email and execute code from within the user's session. Edit: Also please do not tell someone asking for security advices "there is nothing to fear".

Comment: @SebastianS Exact. An attacker can send a malicious mail, and execute code. And what can he do with the XSS executed code ? make a <b></b> attack ? changing your CSS from blue to red ? Are you kidding ? Omg, please learn. Without Java**script** you can do nothing > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Server-side_versus_DOM-based_vulnerabilities

Comment: How about triggering the forward-button (stealing information) or reply-to-all button (spamming)? Just because you can not think of any attacks it doesn't there aren't any. You don't know the web application, paul is planning

Comment: @SebastianS a *reply* button, where ? Paul want to display mails content. He does nowhere talk about actions. "  You don't know the web application, paul is planning ", I know what Paul describes here, Im not in his brain. It's a basic rule in SO to describe properly your issue. Have a good day.

Comment: _Without Javascript you can do nothing_ (Aside from Scriptless XSS): Exactly. Thats the whole point of his question. Thats why preventing script execution is so important. You don't know the application, so you can not make assumptions about an attack. Is it so hard to imagine, that the application has some features, the attacker wants to use with the user's session?

Comment: @SebastianS you're right in digging it. But there is a moment where one need to state, and go to the next step. //// You wont get a full security study here. Nor magic. Worst, you could be banned for too wide question, and not a code/developpment matter. iframe and script escape is suffisant for what you described here, widely suffisant.