# How to add a disabled internal Style node to HTML5 DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, html

As per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) the style tag can be disabled with `disabled` attribute. I tried the below:

```
<head>
    <style>body { color: black; }</style>
    <style disabled>body {color: red; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World !!
</body>
```

Both Chrome and Firefox does not respect that `disabled` attribute and use the red color. IE 11 works correctly (shows black text).

**Question:** How to add internal style nodes in disabled state (in JS)?

---

Context: 
I am dynamically loading a css file content as a style node, to do some rule-processing with `document.sytleSheets.cssRules` etc. I do not want the current page styles to be affected by the presence of this temporary loaded style.

Setting `document.sytleSheets[].disabled` works, but there is a lag between node insertion and the disabled state.

Tried using `new DOMParser().parseFromString(cssFileContent, "text/html")`, which works (completely invisible) fine in loading the html content, but does not initialize the `document.sytleSheets`

Comment: Disabled style elements? That's new :D Do you happen to have some more info about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to add internal style nodes in disabled state (in JS)?

The [`HTMLStyleElement` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#htmlstyleelement) has a `disabled` flag, so you'd use that:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
// ...usual style stuff...
style.disabled = true;
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
```

Of course, if a browser doesn't support disabled style elements (yet), doing that won't have any effect. It's unlikely to cause an error, though, as a browser that doesn't have the `disabled` element will treat it like an "expando" property anyway, so it'll be harmless.

---

> Context: I am dynamically loading a css file content as a style node, to do some rule-processing with document.sytleSheets.cssRules etc. I do not want the current page styles to be affected by the presence of this temporary loaded style.

Since you've found issues with the level of support for disabled style elements, you might consider using a hidden `iframe` instead: ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/gicoqoxaku/edit?html,output) — Stack Snippets don't allow iframes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This text should be black.</p>
</script>
<script>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
var html = "<html><head><style>body { color: red; }</style></head><body></body></html>";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "First rule: " + iframe.contentDocument.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
This text should be black.

First rule: body { color: red; }
```

...with the text in black, not red.

*(Credit to [mschr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1363613/mschr) for [the code to add the iframe with inline HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433550/157247) reliably cross-browser.)*

Comment: don't know for 42 but FF 43.0.b does support disabled property on HTMLStyleElement and so does Chrome 46

Comment: @Kaiido: Cool, I was just going by what the OP said, giving them a reliable alternative.

Comment: Yep and it's the one that made me upvote your answer ! :-)

Comment: The reference to `iframe.contentWindow.document.write` technique is very useful. Thanks much for pointing to it @T.J.Crowder