# Refreshing an iframe after adding a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

to explain the problem here is a short description of the context:

I am building project micro sites for the programming work that students did in their semester. To showcase the work (it is done in processing p5js) I want to use Iframes where the script will run in.

To do this I did it like described here:
https://github.com/processing/p5.js-website/blob/master/js/examples.js#L133

Because the files are coming from an backend I do it like this: I create an iframe and after wards I want to add the script files to it. How ever it does not render anything.

```
<div class="col-sm-7 middle-col col-sm-offset-3">

    <iframe id="uid" width="100%" height="500" src="assets/p5/p5-iframe-template.html"></iframe>

  <script> 
    var iframe = document.getElementById("uid");

    iframe.onload = function() {
       var userScript = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
       userScript.type = 'text/javascript';
       userScript.src = '<?php echo(($content->pfile()->toFile()->url())) ?>';
       userScript.async = false;
       iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(userScript);
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

The problem now is that if I get the url of the file and append it, it seems that the iframe does not reload itself and nothing gets displayed (just a blank white canvas).

If I try a different approach and change the script tag's text property like this:

```
userScript.text = '<?php echo(($content->pfile()->toFile()->content())) ?>';
```

I will get a Javascript error that looks like the following:

[image]

Either way I'm doing it I can not find a solution. I tried refreshing the Iframe by changing it's src attribute but this does not seem to work?
Maybe you can help me out.

Related posts I already read and tried:
[Creating an iframe with given HTML dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically/10433550#10433550)

Greetings

Comment: the first way you shown (injecting script with `.src` set) should work. Maybe problem is with the script you're injecting?

Comment: @eithedog can you further explain whats the problem here and maybe you can give me some insight of how I can work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `<?php echo(($content->pfile()->toFile()->url())) ?>` returns url to your script, your first approach should work **if** iframe actually finishes loading. It might **not** run the event at all (I sadly don't know under what cirumstances it happens - it however happens), and it might be why your approach doesn't work.

You can try to manually check if iframe has loaded by accessing `readyState` property: `iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState` and checking if it's either `interactive` or `complete` and then run adding of the `<script>` within iframe.

Now, your second approach will fail because you're inserting the source code of target script file into your `<script>`, which will fail because you're not escaping `'` or `\n`, and that's what the error is telling you (strings can be broken in JS by using `\` at the end of line). I'd not try this approach if I were you (but yes, if you escape at least those two characters it would work, I don't know however what other caveats you might encounter).

What you might try is attach the source code in a `<script type='template-or-whatever-really-as-long-its-not-text/javascript'><?php echo(($content->pfile()->toFile()->content())) ?></script>` and then move script from the one within your document to the one created within the iframe via `innerHTML`.

Of course, if iframe doesn't trigger the onload event then it amounts to nothing, so I'd look at that first.

Ah, one more thing I've noticed right now - in your first screenshot you're accessing relative path, but in second one the iframe's path is absolute; so it might be that the problem is CORS - in such case while onload event will trigger, you won't be able to add any script to loaded document.

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped me out.
To that CORS related thing: I was writing relative paths on that template src because the code highlighting of stackoverflow did not display my <?php tagged code (or removed it?) so I just hard coded it in. In my code the path is both absolute.
I am using the src solution now and check the ready state property.

What is still missing is, that I need to add the string: `new p5();\n` to the javascript file. Maybe I can do that on the server side when uploading the js file into the CMS. Adding it via `userScript.text += 'new p5();\n';`does not do the trick.

Comment: I think you should be able to call the parent window class from within the iframe by doing something like this - `iframe.contentWindow.__p5__ = new p5()`