# How to run HTML code from a js function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making my own IDE and I need a way of running code(HTML) from a JavaScript function call.

I have a div I need the user to click a button then the div will contain html which is from a textarea.

*By **RUNNING HTML CODE** I mean to get input from a text area and dump it into a div so it it running in the div*

(my IDE is by far the best workspace) [My Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIFgX.jpg)

Here is my CODE:`

```
<textarea class="txtarea"></textarea>

<div class="browser">A Browser</div>

<button class="run-btn">RUN</button>

<script>

var num = 0;
$(".browser").hide(); // hide my div
$(".run-btn").click(function() {
  num++;
  if (num % 2 == 1) {
    $(".txtarea").hide();
    $(".browser").show(); // my div
    $(".browser").text($(".txtarea").val());
  }
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    $(".txtarea").show();
    $(".browser").hide();
  }
});


</script>
```

Comment: Okay.  What do you mean by "run HTML", what have you tried, and what went wrong?  Please edit the question to include all relevant code.

Comment: wat? just get textarea.value and insert it somewhere (or in your div).

Comment: Didn't work :( @Gouverneur

Comment: Show us the code that should do the insertion. This should be trivial for an IDE engineer. (sorry)

Comment: I've Edited it hopefully its better now, @mplungjan

Comment: We still do not know what you mean by "running code(HTML)" - perhaps show some html too?

Comment: What's the issue with the code you have?

Comment: You really shouldn't be writing an IDE if you're trying to "run HTML code".

Comment: Im sort'f making a <i>browser</i> to quickly see the code. @BrandonIbbotson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use an IFrame instead of a DIV to render your entered HTML code.

This questions shows how to create programmatically an IFrame containing your HTML code: [Creating an iframe with given HTML dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks it helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code but I am not getting what is the issue. Everything is working fine.

Comment: I have uploaded the above code in jsfiddle. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/charlie156/hg5468hs/

Comment: When i click 'run'  i only get code, i need compiled code.

Comment: @Zak The Hat change the $(blahblahblah).text to .html