# How to dynamically create an Iframe in jasmine and test it?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jasmine

I need to dynamically create an iframe with some HTML and test it with Jasmine.
This is a way how I create an Iframe - [Creating an iframe with given HTML dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically)

```
var iframe;
beforeEach(() => {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var html = '<body><div class="bar">Foo</div></body>';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
});
```

But there is no content created inside that iframe:

```
it('working with IFRAME',
    inject([SomeAngular2Component],
        (component: SomeAngular2Component) => {
            console.log(iframe) // -> <iframe></iframe> NO INNER HTML HERE
            //component.methodForIframe.(iframe);
            //expect().toBe();
}));
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: When you console.log iframe after creating it, what properties do you see?

Comment: Just `<iframe></iframe>`

Comment: Is it possible to do iframe.src = ... and add create a file or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419102/618794

Comment: This way make an error
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fn.apply(that, arguments)')`

Comment: I see, going back to your initial attempt, could try iframe.onload = function(){// add content}

Comment: I also tried this way. Basically it do nothing. There is nothing happened inside `iframe.onload`.
I test it with setTimeout up to 10 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125781/discussion-between-sergey-a-and-undefined).