# Test the content of an <iframe> in a React component with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, sinon, enzyme

I've written a simple React component that renders an `<iframe>`:

```
export class Iframe extends React.component {
   render() {
        return <iframe src={ this.props.src } />;
    }
}
```

and I trying to test it by checking that the content loaded with `src` is properly populated within the `<iframe>`.
In order to do so I try to access `frame.contentWindow`, but after mounting it with Enzyme it always returns `undefined`.

I've tried to mock the `<iframe>` content with Sinon [`FakeXMLHttpRequest`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer):

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith('GET', 'test', [200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }, '<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><div class="myClass">Amazing Unicorn</div></body></html>']);
container = mount(<Iframe src='test' />);
```

and with [`<iframe src='data:text/html' >`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419102/372899):

```
const src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><div class="myClass">Amazing Unicorn</div></body></html>';
container = mount(<Iframe src={ src } />);
```

but in both cases on the test with Enzyme:

```
container = mount(<Iframe src='...' />);
container.instance().contentWindow // equals 'undefined'
container.find('iframe').contentWindow // equals 'undefined'
```

The component works and renders as expected on the browser when provided with a valid `src` attribute. Is there any way to access `contentWindow` in React tests with Enzyme (or any other test framework)?

Comment: I am having the same issue to test it, did you find a solution?

Comment: You would have to setup enzyme with a "working" browser. Don't know if that is possible. However, why should you want to test this? IMHO this test is pointless as you would not test your code but react. I think you should just test if the prop "src" is passed down correctly as the iframe's "src" attribute which is possible with enzyme.

Comment: contentWindow will be actually null not undefined, after you getDOMNode() and check property contentWindow. what you checked is property contentWindow on enzyme wrapper not iframe itself

Answer (score 2):

The problem is still actual. And the answer is that jsdom provides contentWindow/contentDocument only for attached iframe, and enzyme by default doesn't attach nodes. There is option for mount which directs enzyme to attach node:

```
el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(el);
wrapper = mount(<MyReactNode />, { attachTo: el });
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're writing a unit test (and I assume that this is what you're doing), you should test the behavior, not the implementation details.

If I had to write a test for such component I'd use smth like that:

- positive scenario: component renders an iframe with passed `src`
- negative scenario: component renders null (depends on business logic) if no `src` passed in props

This test handles both: correct and incorrect behavior. See [*Defensive programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) for more details.

If we're talking about the test implementation, I'd use [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) and `toMatchSnapshot` method to check the rendering result on both scenarios.

Comment: I'd agree that this is the typical path, however there are use cases for writing a unit test which validates content inside of an iframe. Example: I can click on a button inside the iframe and trigger an event within my application (outside the iframe).