# Show new, dynamically parsed HTML document jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, domparser

I have two [html](/questions/tagged/html)documents:

- For the main content.
- One that contains an `iframe` using an external URL.

The URL to that `iframe` is created dynamically using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

I want to avoid having two different [html](/questions/tagged/html)documents but rather want to create a new [html](/questions/tagged/html)document dynamically that contains the `iframe`, like:

```
var dynamic_img_path = 'my_external_url';
var html_to_parse = '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"><title>my title</title><style type="text/css">html {margin: 0;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;}iframe {position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;top: 0;border: 0;}</style></head><body><h1>my heading 1</h1><iframe id="iframe-id" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src='+ url_param +'></iframe></body></html>';
```

I then parse the string `html_to_parse` to a [dom](/questions/tagged/dom):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var new_html = parser.parseFromString(html_to_parse, "text/html");
```

This results in an [html](/questions/tagged/html)document as I want it.

But how can I display this new [html](/questions/tagged/html)? I.E. How can I use this as I would with a standard `window.location` change, so that this new [html](/questions/tagged/html)is shown?

Comment: It isn't a jQuery approach, what about to use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: This got me close. window.document.body.innerHTML = new_html.documentElement.innerHTML; However, the iframe url doesn't load.

Comment: By the way, console.dir might be useful to help you debug this problem.

Comment: This post might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Your solution with `window.document.body.innerHTML = new_html.documentElement.innerHTML` works for me and loads the dynamic iframe src. Happy to accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. My answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the body's `innerHTML` to the `documentElement.innerHTML` like so:

```
window.document.body.innerHTML = new_html.documentElement.innerHTML
```