# Iframe display incomplete page using jQuery-Ajax REST API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I use jQuery and ajax for REST API call and set the response to iframe. The target url returns html. It was successful but iframe shows plain page without any text formatting and other functionality. I have attached the images of actual and expected page result (part of page).

Do you how what is wrong with my code? I'm open for any suggestions or if you have better approach to get my expected result.

[expected page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXRSp.jpg)

[actual page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3NnF.jpg)

Below are my codes:

```
function loadPage()
{     
  $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic 123eewd45'
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#myiframe').contents().find('html').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

### Iframe:

```
 <iframe onload="loadPage()"
        id="myiframe">
</iframe>
```

Thank you!

Comment: why are you using iframe again?

Comment: Is you page in https or http?

Comment: so the problem is that styles are not seen?

Comment: Because the url will return a html page with forms. Is there better way to show the page?

Comment: @AndrejsGubars, yes the styles are not there.

Comment: @AlexMufatti, its http

Comment: You need to add a stylesheet to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/217820/5545947

Comment: What is the content of your data variable? The whole page with css included?

Comment: The contents of data would be a server side generated html string. (i guess)

Comment: @AndrejsGubars, yes. But if it is only the "body" part of the html page the problem is that the css is not loaded in the ifame. If the data variable include "header" part the problem can be a x-frame-option header

Comment: Well it seems that only divs and inputs are generated, not proper html document.

Answer (score 0):

i think your css missing on that page please check that link u r style sheet (css) on that page

Comment: if you provide an answer, please provide an example. The explanation you gave is enough for the comment.

Comment: Do i need to copy the css of target url to my code?

Comment: using javascript you can add a stylesheet.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars, how come when i tried to call directly the other site from iframe without using javascript (<iframe src="URL"></iframe>) the page shows fine. without changing my css.

Comment: if you check the src you will see the stylesheet attached.

Comment: this solution should give you indication on how to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433550/5545947