# JavaScript write iframe html from string?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an `iframe`, created like this:

```html
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Now, I also have a string in my `JavaScript`:

```js
var myString = `\
<html>\
    <head>\
    </head>\
    <body>\
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>\
    </body>\
</html>\
`
```

I want to write the `iframe` code from this string. Ideally, in a perfect world, I would use something like this:

```js
myFrame.write(myString); //Obviously this wouldn't work
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an iframe with given HTML dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically)

Answer (score -1):

According to W3Schools you can do the same by other method like:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Here `srcdoc` attribute specifies the HTML content of the page to show in the inline frame.
Source: [Link1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp)

But You want answer to do the same from javascript
use the jquery and html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         function Iframecont(){
              
                var myFrame = $("#myframe").contents().find('body');
                var htmlcontent = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
                myFrame.html(htmlcontent);
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe id="myframe" onload="Iframecont()"></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It's 2023 https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Hi @youmightnootneedjquery What's the problem in this. This is also work.

Comment: @NavinSingh, Thanks for your response! What if I need to add an external script/CDN inside the `head` tag? Would I be able to do it with `.find('head')`?

Comment: @Anye, For creating element or overwrite in head just like want to write or overwrite some meta tag so you can try in this method: ```<script type="text/javascript">
var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
metaTag.name = "viewport"
metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4"
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
</script>``` In the same method you can write external script/cdn using `append`.