# How to preview html in textarea in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am using a textarea in which I am allowing the user to enter his html.

When the user is enter the HTML there is a option of preview (button), when the user click on Preview button, then the textarea is hid and the html is shown in a div.

When the user is entering some html with body tag etc the design of the page is disturbed.

Any way to solve it

The problem I am facing is when a preview is generated.

demo HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contest Announcement</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0 auto; padding:0; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#outlook a {padding:0;} 
#backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
.ExternalClass {width:100%;}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}

img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block; border:none;} 
p {margin: 1em 0;}
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}

.symbolfix img{width:10px !important;height:10px !important;}

</style>

</head>

<body style="width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0 auto; padding:0; background-color:#FFFFFF;">
```

Comment: Do you have any rules for what HTML needs to be entered here? Validate it before showing a preview. Otherwise post the HTML to server and load it in an iframe.

Comment: 1- The preview is done from client side
2- is there a way I can validate it as well on client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most ideal, but why not try using javascript & jQuery to assign the content of the text area to an iframe? Here is a link to a post which details how to go about injecting the HTML in to an iframe.

[putting html inside an iframe (using javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620881/putting-html-inside-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WYSIWYG editor to accomplish this easily.

check out [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)

Comment: @Evostract Oh .. i see. Maybe you could post your code here or on jsfiddle with a link... easier to solve issues when we can see the code.

Comment: See User can enter any type of html but Still I have edited the post for a demo html he is trying to use